# Error django_cassandra_engine' isn't an available database backend

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I was trying to use cassandra using django_cassandra_engine but I keep on gettingthe below error

```
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_cassandra_engine' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name connection_created
```

Any idea on why this error?Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you configure `django.db.backends` ?

Comment: yes I have put  'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',

Comment: `pip install django-cassandra-engine` and `INSTALLED_APPS = (... 'django_cassandra_engine', ...) done ?

Comment: yes I dis that too.Am I missing any configuration part

Comment: https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine#usage this has full configuration.

Comment: Last link work for you ?

Comment: It seems that django-cassandra-engine should be in the same path